# Using String variable as an expression

Tags: vb.net, string, compiler-construction, command

Passing commands as variables. I am creating a POP3 client and was crunching through some code when I though of something interesting.

Is it possible to pass strings of vb code to an object so that the object will execute it. I am relatively familiar with vb.net's source code being converted to Intermediate language and then being thrown into a JIT virtual machine, but I was hoping there was a simple way to implement this idea.

I want to be able to use strings

```
Dim Command as string 
    Command = "If a + b > 0 then c = a + b" '<----syntactical sugar!
    System.Compiler.Something.execute(command)
```

If anyone has any direction, or any correction to any of the above. I appreciate your time.

Rah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start you may want to check out the open source [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) project. 
 The Runtime.ClassBuilder class in that project creates a .Net class from text, which can then be used as a normal class.

Comment: This looks more like I would have to build my own library of commands and trigger them through File Helpers, which is cool. I was looking for a direct vein into the framework though. Where I could use syntax as if I was in design mode and hit run.

Comment: I'll have to post more on this one after I boil it down a bit.